# Using a nested variable in un-nested argument

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
#Previously defined variables
col_cp1_tariff_time_1_hour = 0
col_cp1_tariff_time_2_hour = 7
col_cp1_tariff_time_3_hour = 21
col_cp1_tariff_time_4_hour = 0
col_cp1_tariff_time_5_hour = 0

p1_time_variable_bands = 4

current_tariff_type = 1


time_cents_questions = [
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (hours[0]),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (hours[1]),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (hours[2]),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (hours[3]),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (hours[4])]

#Application
if current_tariff_type == 1: #Time of use

    print("enter the corresponding tariffs.\nEnter for period 1: ")

    hours = (col_cp1_tariff_time_1_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_2_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_3_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_4_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_5_hour)

    variable_bands = []

    for question in time_cents_questions[0:int(p1_time_variable_bands)-1]: #Change variable
        try:
            cents = int(input(question))
            variable_bands.append(cents)
        except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
            variable_bands.append(0)

    try:
        [col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_1_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_2_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_3_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_4_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_5_cents] = variable_bands
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        variable_bands.append(0) #Change variable
```

It's triggering the error:
NameError: name 'hours' is not defined

Is there a way to define my nested 'hours' variable as the hours variable that time_cents_questions should use?

Comment: It's because you have defined variable `hours` after the variable `time_cents_questions`. Try to move `hours` definition before `time_cents_questions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, do the string formatting after `hours` is defined:

```
#Previously defined variables
col_cp1_tariff_time_1_hour = 0
col_cp1_tariff_time_2_hour = 7
col_cp1_tariff_time_3_hour = 21
col_cp1_tariff_time_4_hour = 0
col_cp1_tariff_time_5_hour = 0

p1_time_variable_bands = 4

current_tariff_type = 1


time_cents_questions = [
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n",
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n",
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n",
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n",
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n"]

#Application
if current_tariff_type == 1: #Time of use

    print("enter the corresponding tariffs.\nEnter for period 1: ")

    hours = (col_cp1_tariff_time_1_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_2_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_3_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_4_hour,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_5_hour)

    variable_bands = []

    for idx,question in enumerate(time_cents_questions[0:int(p1_time_variable_bands)-1]): #Change variable
        try:
            cents = int(input(question%hours[idx]))
            variable_bands.append(cents)
        except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
            variable_bands.append(0)

    try:
        [col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_1_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_2_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_3_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_4_cents,
         col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_5_cents] = variable_bands
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        variable_bands.append(0) #Change variable
```

Comment: @Deskjokey Thanks for your accept, since you have > 15 reputation you can upvote